# Fitting a closed curve to a set of discrete points and finding it's perimeter

Tags: python, curve-fitting, spline

I have a set of points pts which form a loop which looks like this:
[Closed curve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JoLeQ.png)

The code I used for the same is as follows:

```
  pts=np.array( [ [1145,1130],
                [1099.5,1056.5],
                [1026,1062],
                [950.3,1054.3],
                [909,1130],
                [940.4,1215.6],
                [1026,1264],
                [1111.6,1215.6]
                ])


    pts = np.vstack([pts, pts[0]])
    #pts = np.array([...]) # Your points

    x, y = pts.T
    i = np.arange(len(pts))

    # 5x the original number of points
    interp_i = np.linspace(0, i.max(), 5 * i.max())

    xi = interp1d(i, x, kind='cubic')(interp_i)
    yi = interp1d(i, y, kind='cubic')(interp_i)

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.plot(xi, yi)
    ax.plot(x, y, 'ko')
    plt.show()
```

I want to know how to find the length of this curve/ the perimeter of this figure. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: The points are linked in the order they're given, what else did you expect?

Comment: @ThierryLathuille oops, thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can approach the perimeter of the curve to a sum of line segments.

If (xj,yj) and (xj+1,yj+1) are coordinates of start and end points of a line segment lying on the xy plane, then its length can be written as:

```
L_j = sqrt{[x_(j+1) - x_(j)]^2 + [y_(j+1) - y_(j)]^2}
```

So you can just sum over all L_j segments to get the approximate value for the perimeter of a closed curve.

A python code example to do it is:

```
L = np.sqrt((xi[-1] - xi[0])**2 + (yi[-1] - yi[0])**2) # let the initial value of L be the length of the line segment between the last and the first points
for j in range(0,len(xi)):
  L = L + np.sqrt((xi[j+1] - xi[j])**2 + (yi[j+1] - yi[j])**2)
print L
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! One can increase the number of interpolation points to get a more accurate result using the same approach as yours